# Is there an equivalent of str_replace in C++?

Tags: c++, replace

In PHP, there is a [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) function that basically does a find and replace. Is there an equivalent of this function in C++?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/ will perform a string replace but won't do a search and replace.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not exactly, but take a look at the [Boost String Algorithms Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/string_algo.html) - in this case the [replace functions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id1761425):

```
std::string str("aabbaadd");    
boost::algorithm::replace_all(str, "aa", "xx");
```

`str` now contains `"xxbbxxdd"`.

Comment: @Kugel: What are you aiming at? The string algorithms are abstract and work with any string fulfilling the [requirements](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/string_algo/design.html#string_algo.string). So go with `wstring`, use Boost.Locale with ICU or whatever fits best.

Comment: why would someone use boost for this basic functionality?

Answer (score 7):

`std::string::replace` will do replacement. You can couple it with `std::string::find*` methods to get similar functionality. It's not as easy as the PHP way. I think Boost has what you're looking for though; in [regular expressions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use std::regex_replace